# Setting table columns to sibling columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Due to some dirty data I have an issue where I need to set some columns in a table equal to their sibling columns after some string modification.

IE:

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET
    column1 = column2
    ,column2 = column3
    ,column4 = column5 
    ,column5 = SUBSTRING(column6,1,1)
    ,column6 = RIGHT(column6, LEN(column6) - 1)
```

However this is not going to work (because these set commands are not executing in order). Is there a better way to go about this than individually writing out a subquery for each?

Comment: why don't you execute the update for one column each based on your desired order?

Comment: @vkp Ya that's what I was going to do but wanted to see if there was an cool way to do it all in one update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try it wiht an updateable CTE

*wanted to see if there was an cool way* - uhm - cool enough?

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT column1 
          ,column2 AS NewCol1
          ,column2
          ,column3 AS NewCol2
          ,column4
          ,column5 AS NewCol4
          ,column5
          ,SUBSTRING(column6,1,1) AS NewCol5
          ,column6
          ,RIGHT(column6, LEN(column6) - 1) AS NewCol6
    FROM YourTbl
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET column1=NewCol1
                        ,column2=NewCol2
                        ,column4=NewCol4
                        ,column5=NewCol5
                        ,column6=NewCol6;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work as long as You use microsoft sql-server. They are not executed one by one, but assigned as a whole, You can swap values this way:

```
UPDATE someTable SET a = b, b = a
```

It would not work on mysql though.

Comment: Interesting. Can I swap with more than a pair? I'll have to try multiple when i get back to it. Thanks

Comment: @40Alpha Yes. Have a look here http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/Importance_of_Column_Order_in_SET_Clause.html I would love to see it in the specifications like for mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html , unfortunately I did not find it for sql-server (yet).